# What's the scenario of share session on server side?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

What's the scenario of share session on server side? And is there some approach to share the session on server side in JAVA EE platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the problem does not explicitly say the objects between which session needs to be shared, I can suggest following options:

1) If you need to share session between different web apps on the same server (tomcat) , you can use:

```
<Host name="localhost" ...>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
</Host>
```

2) If the server is not tomcat, please refer to SSO option for the respective server.

3) You can as well use a full fledged SSO product like CAS (http://www.jasig.org/cas) which will allow you to share sessions across apps across different servers but not between users.

4) If you need to share session between different users, all you need to do is pass on the session ids between different clients (typically browsers) based upon your share criteria like, people playing same game, accessing same bulletin board and can collaboratively changing the data. However, please understand most of the security infrastructure is built around mapping of session ids. If you choose to make the session ids explicitly accessible between multiple users, you would have to re-create lots of security filters yourself.

5) Alternatively, best approach will be to manage the state of the object differently from session. The state of the shared object can be shared across multiple sessions in much more standards compliant secure and auditable way.

Comment: I know that SSO just avoid multiple login to same Security Realm, it don't share session. By definition the JEE standard specify that the session is isolated between web application, but Websphere has non standard configuration for enable session sharing.

Answer (score 0):

On Java EE you must review the Servlet Specification, the object HttpSession provides the behavior for manage the session on the server side.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html

Although you can store any object in the session, this practice can be dangerous because the objects remain on session until it expires or the object is removed, so if your program doesn't manage well the objects that are stored in the session you can consume to many heap memory.

The objects of session are deleted when it expires, the expiration time is configured in the deployment descriptor web.xml or can be set by client. If you don't specify a time for session expiration then the default is 30 minutes, this 30 minutes are counted from the last request made by the user.

My recommendation is that you don't store objects in session, you must use the object HttpServletRequest and the mehtos setAttribute and getAttribute for pass objects between requests. I you need store a value on session you can store the ID of a product instead the whole product. A common use of the session is for store variables that must live for more than a request and you don't want to store it on cockles for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but seems your answer is not the answer for my question, you just add some comments/practices about using session I suppose.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?